# Como implementar um inputText para "Tags" ou "palavras-chave" no Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, input, app

Estou criando um app android e preciso de um inputText simples que permita que o usuário digite "tags" muito parecido com o campo de perguntas aqui do site. Como eu implemento isso? preciso de alguma biblioteca externa? Já revirei tudo e nenhuma solução funcionou [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é o MaterialChipsInput

**Documentação**: https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/5584

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, essa documentação me ajudou bastante. Porém gostaria que, além de uma lista com tags ja pré definidas, o usuário pudesse digitar suas próprias livremente em caso de n haver a tag desejada na lista. Como posso adaptar para essa funcionalidade??

Comment: pareceu complexo no início, mas a documentação explica tudo que precisava.